# if statement, OR

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I am trying to check if a field is not one of two values then show a message.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong

```
If  LegalEntity <> "ETL" or "RGB" Then
           Shell.RedoMessage = "Holiday Carry Over and Trading is not enabled for     your Legal Entity. Please click the Cancel button above"
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you need to check that the value of **LegalEntity** is not **"ETL"** nor **"RGB"**.

Then it shoud be like this:

```vb
'if its not equal to ETL and not equal to RG the enter the condition
If LegalEntity <> "ETL" And LegalEntity <> "RGB" Then
    Shell.RedoMessage = "Holiday Carry Over and Trading is not enabled for your Legal Entity. Please click the Cancel button above"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks i updated the answer i was on a hurry .

Comment: @LeeS please accept answer for feedbacking other answering pursuers